# Artifactory build options for maven build and issues

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am new to Artifactory and I find that there is a lot of documentation on the different ways to get artifacts to Artifactory but nothing that is complete.

For example:
The pipeline plugin used by jenkins:
sample code:

```
node {
    def server = Artifactory.newServer url: SERVER_URL, credentialsId: CREDENTIALS
    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

    stage 'Build'
        git url: 'https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git'

    stage 'Artifactory configuration'
        rtMaven.tool = MAVEN_TOOL // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
        rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
        rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'libs-release', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot', server: server
        def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

    stage 'Exec Maven'
        rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install', buildInfo: buildInfo

    stage 'Publish build info'
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
}
```

I am not sure how to set up some variables like CREDENTIALS. specially if I want to use api key not user id and password.

Also, if I want to use the Artifactory rest API to build and promote my project(Maven Build). should I be using:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/build" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --upload-file build.json
```

Where build.json is the sample JSON at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API under Build Upload. 
If i use the API do i still need the above jenkins plugin code or can just use the API?
Where do I pass my credentials (Userid and APi key) in the curl command?

If any experienced user could guide me with these questions that will be of great help.